# init error, laptop do not boot

Tags: boot, laptop, init

I turned my computer on and it comes up with ways to boot and I clicked *Ubuntu with linux 2.6.38-13-generic*. There was a recovery mode too. Once I clicked its writing come up:

```
init: udevtrigger main process (93) terminated with status 1
init: udevtrigger post stop process (97) terminated with status 1
init: udevtrigger main process (92) killed by TERM signal
mountall: disconnected from plymouth
init: plymouth-splash main processs (98 ) terminated with status 2
init: plymouth main process (50) killed by SEGV signal
```

I have no idea what this means and my laptop don't boot. I tried recovery mode but it comes up with similar things. I don't know why this has happened. It can be because I tried upgrading my Ubuntu to 11.0 and I shutdown the laptop before it finished? 
i would be most grateful if you could help
amna

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would recommend doing is boot the laptop with ubuntu 11.10 usb ( 32bit if you had install 32 bit ubuntu on your computer or 64-bit accordingly.)

The next step is to `fsck /dev/????` ???? would be replaced with the device name.

Create directory for mounting the filesystem to root into. 
`mkdir /tmp/mntdir`

Then mount it . `mount /dev/???? /tmp/mntdir` and then remount
`mount --bind /dev/ /tmp/mntdir/dev/`

`mount --bind /sys/ /tmp/mntdir/sys/`

`mount --bind /proc/ /tmp/mntdir/proc/`

Then run `chroot /tmp/mntdir/`

after chrooting run `sudo apt-get update` then depending on `sudo apt-get -f install`
You might be asked to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

and finally for safety sake run " sudo grub-install /dev/sda?" and you should be ready to reboot and boot into ubuntu.